# Checkbox does not display properly in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have a checkbox that does not render as a checkbox and would be **displayed as something similar to a button**. However, it behaves like a checkbox where I can select it and the handler  works with the firing event.

Here is my checkbox. I also tried it outside the  or , but it has the same behavior. There is **no CSS** related to checkbox or the part that I am working on. I am using **Flex 4.5** though.

1- Has anybody encounter such a problem?

2- Is there any way to enforce the layout inside a container and item renderer?

```
<mx:HBox>
    <mx:CheckBox id="Test"
        label="Label"
        fontWeight="bold"                                
                change="Test_changeHandler(event)"/>        
</mx:HBox>
```

Comment: What is the problem? The syntax of your question is very confusing.

Comment: the checkbox is displayed as a button

Comment: That is very strange. Everything appears correct, so I have no idea where the problem could come from without seeing more code.

Comment: do you have any idea about my second question? any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using a custom theme?  Which version of the Flex SDK are you using?  Can you provide a runnable sample so we can test your code and see the problem ourselves?  I don't understand your second question.  What is the layout you want to enforce?  Inside which container?  Inside an itemRenderer for what?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you mean by the question. It depends on the layout you're trying to enforce, the specific container and what the itemrenderer is rendering.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Flex 4.5, why are you using Flex 3 components?  Change this to spark components and everything should be much better:

```
<s:HGroup>
    <s:CheckBox id="Test"
        label="Label"
        fontWeight="bold"                                
                change="Test_changeHandler(event)"/>        
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: I am using Flex 4.5, but I also want to be compatible to previous ones.

Comment: @paradisonoir, that's illogical and doesn't make *any* sense.  If you're using any spark components, it makes it incompatible with Flex 3 automatically.  Even then, why would you care for it to be reverse compatible?

Comment: I am not using spark. I am using <mx:HBox> and  <mx:CheckBox>.

Comment: Could of sworn you had `<s:HGroup>` in your example before.  I also still don't understand what's your reluctance in using Flex 4...

Answer (score 3):

`mx:CheckBox` extends `mx:Button`, so if you put added css that skinned `mx:Button`, `mx:CheckBox` would also get it. It's a shortcoming of flex 3 skinning. You can workaround by explicitly setting the `mx:CheckBox` skin.

---

**Edit:** try this

```
<mx:HBox>
    <mx:CheckBox id="Test"
        label="Label"
        fontWeight="bold"                                
        skin="{mx.skins.spark.CheckBoxSkin}"
        change="Test_changeHandler(event)"
        />        
</mx:HBox>
```

Comment: I tried to add an explicit formatting to mx:CheckBox but still there is no luck. I also used skinClass: ClassReference("mx.skins.CheckBoxSkin"); or skin:ClassReference("mx.skins.ProgrammaticSkin"); but still there is no difference. Any guess?

Comment: I've added an example, but I agree with J_A_X, I think you should use the spark components.

Answer (score 1):

This happend to me also. Fix was to use a mx:Container as parent instead of FlexGlobals.application on the popup component.

Answer (score 0):

for the second question:

I had exactly the same problem and i forced it to take the "original" skin with:

```
var skinClass:Class = mx.skins.spark.CheckBoxSkin;
theCheckBoxInstance.setStyle("skin", skinClass);
```

Because in my case the CheckBox was an ItemRenderer for a DataGrid, I've put it in the overridden createChildren methode right after the super call..

I have no explication why this happens. I encountered it in an old monster project where I was charged to make some changes...

Comment: Actually this happened only in a modulated application for me , where the itemRenderer with the Checkbox was used inside a module. Declaring the itemRenderer as a variable in the shell application got me around this problem without forcing the skin to reapply.